# Why is softKeys() deprecated in Guava 10?

Tags: java, guava

As of Guava 10, [`MapMaker.softKeys`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/10.0.1/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html#softValues()) is deprecated, and the corresponding method doesn't exist in [`CacheBuilder`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/10.0.1/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html).

Why was this change made? What do I need to do with existing code that use it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*I wrote the question because, initially, I did genuinely wonder why (as I had existing code that used `softKeys`). However, the reason was obvious on reflection and I decided to post it here, in case someone else also uses `softKeys` and was wondering the same thing.*

In short, the reason was that `softKeys` never made any sense in the first place. Thus, its initial inclusion was in itself a mistake, one which the Guava developers are rectifying via deprecation.

In general, you use soft references if you want the object to stick around for a little after all the strong references are gone; in contrast, with weak references, the object usually gets collected soon once there are no strong or soft references left. This is useful for cached *values* that you want to hold on to temporarily, so that a lookup using the corresponding key will "revive" a strong reference for the value.

However, this behaviour doesn't make any sense for keys:

- Since `softKeys` and `weakKeys` maps use an identity-based lookup, the only way to get at an entry of interest is to posess a strong reference to its key.<sup>†</sup> Thus, once there are no strong key references left, the entry is effectively dead (with no possibility of revival).
- The only practical difference between `softKeys` and `weakKeys` is how long an entry remains in the map after all the strong references to its key are gone. Since such entries are dead anyway, using `softKeys` instead of `weakKeys` only delays the entry's eviction, for no good reason.

Thus, most times when coming across code that uses `softKeys`, a much more suitable replacement is `weakKeys`.

† I am not considering the case of fetching the entry via iteration, or anything other than key-based lookup, since maps are primarily about key-based operations.

Comment: why did `softKeys` use identity match? that was the design of WeakHashMap which it doesn't have to follow. and `softValues` makes no sense to me either; maybe `softEntry` is more proper.

Comment: @irreputable `softValues` means "hold a soft reference to the value and remove the entry if that reference is cleared." It wouldn't make sense to have `softEntries` because you generally aren't going to be holding on to the `Map.Entry` objects.

Comment: You figured all this out on your own!? You're exactly right. It took us three years to realize it. :-)

Comment: @irreputable WeakHashMap doesn't use identity, actually. But identity is the only thing that really makes sense. By using weak or soft keys (as opposed to values) you're indicating that the GC of that key is a significant event -- implying the entry can be cleaned up because it's not likely to be queried again soon. For a value object (with overridden equals()) that's illogical. One reference might be GC'd but there are any number of other ones floating about.

Comment: @KevinBourrillion: Thanks for confirming the rationale "from the horse's mouth". :-) I'll go and mark the post as accepted.

Comment: WeakHashMap is to solve a general modeling problem: adding dynamic fields to any instance. The problem description dictates that it's identity based. A better API woulda been called ObjectLocal, and it coulda been implemented more efficiently. For WeakHashMap, one can look at the particular implementation, and wonder why don't we generalize the weak+key case and add other 3 cases? Sure we can, but this is done without a higher motivation that led to WeakHashMap; so the meaning of the generalized cases is unclear, and it's hard to justify their exact chosen behavior.

Comment: @irreputable (I'm arriving a little late to this thread) a soft reference to a key that is a value object (with overridden equals) seems to make perfect sense since the keys (and their map entries) would then only be discarded when memory becomes scarce. A weak reference to a value object makes not so much sense (except perhaps in a temporal cache). However, with identity-based lookup for soft referenced objects, as in Guava maps, a soft referenced key makes not much sense, but this is because of the insistence on identity-based lookup, not because of the soft reference.

Comment: This answer is missleading because you could use another soft reference to revive a key (make it strong again) and then use it to perform a map lookup. The real reason for deprecating soft keys is that you can substitute them with weak keys. Example: If you use weak keys and additionally store a key somewhere else with a soft reference, then the map key is NOT only weakly reachable and therefor will NOT be garbage collected immediately. So effectivly soft and weak keys are the same and thus soft keys where deprecated. See the answer of @Dimitris Andreou for a full explanation.

Comment: But longer life is an important and irreplaceable reason for soft-keys, is there any other way except soft-keys?

Answer (score 7):

Here is my attempt of explanation of the issue (a little more complete to Chris' response)

http://groups.google.com/group/guava-discuss/browse_thread/thread/764af1e627d6fa0e?pli=1