# Should I make string key to be softkey in Guava?

Tags: java, android, guava

Should I make string key to be softkey in Guava?

Im using it for simple bitmap cache.

```
private final ConcurrentMap<String, Bitmap> imageCache = new MapMaker()
        .softValues()
        .expireAfterAccess(IMAGE_EXPIRATION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .makeComputingMap(new Function<String, Bitmap>() {
            public Bitmap apply(String key) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Image loaded");

                Bitmap bm = null;
                try {
                    URL aURL = new URL(key);
                    URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
                    conn.connect();
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                    bis.close();
                    is.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, e);
                }

                return bm;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you shouldn't use soft keys for anything... it's deprecated in the latest release. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618129/why-is-softkeys-deprecated-in-guava-10/7618134#7618134) for more on why.

Also note that in the latest release [Cache](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html)  and [CacheBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) should be used in preference to creating computing maps with `MapMaker`.

Comment: Yep I know about CacheBuilder. However google http client is still depend on r9.

Comment: Is it resonalbe to use WeakKey in my image cache?

Comment: @AlexeyZakharov: No, you don't want weak keys. With `String` keys, you almost certainly want the keys to be compared using `.equals` equality rather than `==` equality so that two different `String` objects that are equal will be considered the same key. As far as google http client depending on r9... I imagine it wouldn't be using any `@Beta` APIs, so you should be able to replace r9 with 10.0.1 safely.